# Python and SAP HANA without HANA Client

Tags: python, hana

Most tutorials about SAP HANA and Python tell that you need SAP HANA Client in order to interact with SAP HANA from Python.

e.g.

- [SAP HANA and Python? Yes Sir!](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/hana/blog/2012/06/08/sap-hana-and-python-yes-sir)
- [Power of Python Integrated with SAP HANA](http://saphanatutorial.com/sap-hana-and-python/)

So it seems that it was needed a while ago.

But when you try installing SAP HANA Client you realize that it is not available any more.

**So what is the substitute of SAP HANA Client for Python ?**

Comment: which version of HANA do you have and which python client do you mean? To the best of my knowledge, the python client is available with every HANA installation. It should also be available in the HANA express edition. Although it is might appear good to use pyhdb, the official python driver of SAP offers better performance in some cases and more features than the pyhdb client.

Answer (score 9):

Install the API [pyhdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyhdb/0.2.3#install).

The link contains the Description about how to install pyhdb and how to use it. Ceers.

Just be aware that the example assumes `auto-commit = true`

Commands to install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install pyhdb
```

Example (auto-commit = true) :

```
import pyhdb
connection = pyhdb.connect(
    host="example.com",
    port=30015,
    user="user",
    password="secret"
)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 'Hello Python World' FROM DUMMY")
cursor.fetchone()
connection.close()
```

Comment: looks like this client does not support stored procedures as well. Something to keep in mind. I recently tried it, and it worked decently so far.

Answer (score 0):

## Reference: https://github.com/SAP/PyHDB

Some other queries to try

```
## imports
import pandas as pd
import pprint

## Querying a systems table
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM "PUBLIC"."M_CS_TABLES" LIMIT 10')
pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())

## Creating a table:
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE PYHDB_TEST("NAMES" VARCHAR (255) null)')

## Inserting a row to the table:
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PYHDB_TEST VALUES('Testing python 
client')")
pprint.pprint(cursor.rowcount)
```